# Canvas маски png

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

в примере сделана маска из изображений, как реализовать в одном canvas несколько масок?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var truck, logo, overlay;
var newColor = "purple";

var imageURLs = [];
var imagesOK = 0;
var imgs = [];
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/boxTruck.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/TVlogoSmall.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/TVlogoSmallOverlay.png");
loadAllImages();

function loadAllImages() {
  for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    img.onload = function() {
      imagesOK++;
      imagesAllLoaded();
    };
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }
}

var imagesAllLoaded = function() {
  if (imagesOK == imageURLs.length) {
    // all images are fully loaded an ready to use
    truck = imgs[0];
    logo = imgs[1];
    overlay = imgs[2];
    start();
  }
};


function start() {

  // save the context state
  ctx.save();

  // draw the overlay
  ctx.drawImage(overlay, 150, 35);

  // change composite mode to source-in
  // any new drawing will only overwrite existing pixels
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";

  // draw a purple rectangle the size of the canvas
  // Only the overlay will become purple
  ctx.fillStyle = newColor;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // change the composite mode to destination-atop
  // any new drawing will not overwrite any existing pixels
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";

  // draw the full logo
  // This will NOT overwrite any existing purple overlay pixels
  ctx.drawImage(logo, 150, 35);

  // draw the truck
  // This will NOT replace any existing pixels
  // The purple overlay will not be overwritten
  // The blue logo will not be overwritten
  ctx.drawImage(truck, 0, 0);

  // restore the context to it's original state
  ctx.restore();

}
$("#canvas").click(function() {
  newColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  start();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="536" height="402">
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете легко повторить пример из кода в разных (непересекающихся) частях canvas:

```
  // рисуем картинку
  ctx.drawImage(overlay, 150, 35);
  // 'source-in' приводит к тому, что перерисовываются только непрозрачные пиксели:
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";

  // рисуем прямоугольник цвета newColor на весь canvas
  // цвет изменится только у пикселей картинки, нарисованной ранее
  ctx.fillStyle = newColor;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

^^в последней строке укажите интересующий вас кусок canvas.

Еще вы можете [сделать два canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008863/1026):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
 <canvas id="layer1" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
 <canvas id="layer2" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

PS. Ссылка на источник вашего кода: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18387343/1026